# Is there a convenient way to pack multiple ArrayLists into a JsonArray?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I'm trying to setup a webapp to send database tables via JSON. I'd like to send all the entries without much ado. So I read out all the fields as ArrayLists, and now I could just parse them one by one via JSON and send them. But isn't there a convenient way to pack them all into a single JsonArray?

Here is my code example:

```
public static JSONArray[] getDBEntries(String tablename) {
    JSONArray[] js = new JSONArray[5];
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> text = null;
    ArrayList<String> altname = null;
    ArrayList<String> altname2 = null;
    ArrayList<String> icd10 = null;
    ArrayList<String> alphaid = null;
    int index = 0;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/users");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tablename);
        while (rs.next()) {
            text.add(rs.getString("text"));
            if (altname != null) {
                altname.add(rs.getString("altname"));
            }
            if (altname2 != null) {
                altname2.add(rs.getString("altname2"));
            }
            if (icd10 != null) {
                icd10.add(rs.getString("icd10"));
            }
            if (alphaid != null) {
                alphaid.add(rs.getString("alphaid"));
            }
            index++;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (st != null) st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    js[0] = new JSONArray(text);
    js[1] = new JSONArray(altname);
    js[2] = new JSONArray(altname2);
    js[3] = new JSONArray(icd10);
    js[4] = new JSONArray(alphaid);
    return js;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using JSONArray[5], just use a JSONArray and elements to it. Then you return a JSONArray which contains each of the arrays as elements.

Comment: @KDM I'm not quite sure if I got that right: how could I add an `ArrayList` as an element to a `JSONArray`? Is there a way to add multiple JSONArrays to a single JSONArray (nesting)?

Comment: `JSONArray js = new JSONArray();js.add(new JSONArray(text));` etc. should work. A JSONArray can contain all primitives as well as any other JSON objects.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, now it's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add the table data in POJO. Then you can convert that into JsonArray using Gson

```
 class AplPojo {
    private String text;
    private String altname;
    private String altname;
    private String icd10;
    private String alphaid;

     //getter and setters
  }
  public static String getDBEntries(String tablename) {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<AplPojo> aplPojos = new ArrayList<AplPojo>();
    int index = 0;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/users");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tablename);
        while (rs.next()) {
            AplPojo  aplPojo= new AplPojo();
            aplPojo.setText(rs.getString("text"));
            aplPojo.setAltname(rs.getString("altname"));
            aplPojo.setAltname2(rs.getString("altname2")); 
            aplPojo.setIcd10(rs.getString("icd10")); 
            aplPojo.setAlphaid(rs.getString("alphaid"));
            index++;
            aplPojos.add(aplPojo);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (st != null) st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
     // create a new Gson instance
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     // convert your list to jsonArray
     String aplPojosList = gson.toJson(aplPojos);
     return aplPojos;
}
```

Comment: 1 up for reusability, plain and simple solution

Comment: just the if statement was obsolete now, I edited that

Comment: I'm just going nuts parsing it back from JSON, I thought it should work with `ArrayList<AplPojo> entries = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ArrayList<AplPojo>.class)`, but it seems that I'll have to go with iterating over every AplPojo element, or is there something I missed?

Comment: ...found it already: `ArrayList<DBEntries> entries = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<DBEntries>>() {}.getType());` :-)